# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getOnBackInvokedDispatcher()Landroid/window/OnBackInvokedDispatcher;

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Facing error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method
> getOnBackInvokedDispatcher()Landroid/window/OnBackInvokedDispatcher;
> in class Landroid/app/Activity; or its super classes (declaration of
> 'android.app.Activity' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)

This is the complete stacktrace

```
--------- beginning of crash
```

> 2023-05-15 22:39:47.627  2707-2707  AndroidRuntime
> com....apps.nowinandroid.demo.debug  E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.google.samples.apps.nowinandroid.demo.debug, PID: 2707
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method
> getOnBackInvokedDispatcher()Landroid/window/OnBackInvokedDispatcher;
> in class Landroid/app/Activity; or its super classes (declaration of
> 'android.app.Activity' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)
> at
> androidx.activity.ComponentActivity$Api33Impl.getOnBackInvokedDispatcher(ComponentActivity.java:1138)
> at
> androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.onCreate(ComponentActivity.java:382)
> at
> com.google.samples.apps.nowinandroid.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:78)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8257)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8237)
> at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1339)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3660)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3816)
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:99)
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2299)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7850)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)

When I tried to run NIA android app on Android studio Flamingo emulator with TIRAMISU API got this error.

I tried to refresh project and reconfigure but did no change in output.

Comment: For Kotlin :   val dispatcher: OnBackPressedDispatcher = onBackPressedDispatcher

    // Create a callback for back button handling
    val callback = object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
            // Handle back button press here
            // If you want to allow the default behavior, call super.handleOnBackPressed()
        }
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this same error by setting the emulator Android API version to 32. Old version was Tiramisu API.

**steps**

1. Goto Device manager
2. Select emulator device to which the error is happening
3. Update the API to 32 and save configuration
4. Run the app on same emulator (It should work fine)

Comment: That sounds like you haven't fixed anything. Tiramisu is a code name for Android 13 (API 33). By choosing API 32 you downgraded your emulator to Android 12, where this problem doesn't occur.

Answer (score 4):

1> Add the below dependencies in build.gradle file

> implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.8.0-alpha07"

2> Add the below line in the AndroidManifest.xml file under application tag

> android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"

3> Add the below code under on create method

Kotlin :

```
    val dispatcher: OnBackPressedDispatcher = onBackPressedDispatcher

    // Create a callback for back button handling
    val callback = object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
            // Handle back button press here
            // If you want to allow the default behavior, call super.handleOnBackPressed()
        }
    }
```

Java :

```
    OnBackInvokedDispatcher dispatcher = getOnBackInvokedDispatcher();
```